# Connect JSP With MySql Database in Openshift

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, openshift, dbconnection

I am new to **openshift**,I have created some static web applications using openshift.

now I am creating **java web application** in openshift using the **Eclipse IDE**, I need to **connect mySql database** created in the openshift project in my account. when I trying to connect I am getting an **exception**

> Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the
>   server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets
>   from the server.

please look at my code.

**JSP**

```
<body>

<%

try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            out.println(e.getMessage());        
        }

    try{
Connection conn=  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://***.*.**.*:3306/dbName","username","password");
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    out.print(st.executeUpdate("insert into user('shajeer','password')"));
    out.println();

}catch(Exception e){    
    out.println(e.getMessage());
}

%>

</body>
```

I have added **mysql driver** to my project, the url marked as * is as exact ip seen in **phpmyadmin** server url, and user name and password are also correct.

if anyone knows the problem,please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Add mysql driver to the **Deployment Assembly**.

you can done it by : Project properties ->  Deployment Assembly -> Add -> Archives from file system.

Comment: mentioned in the question that mySql driver added. thats not the issue